# How to resize callendar with touch event when using React Fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, frontend, fullcalendar, react-functional-component

How to resize calendar with touch event when using React Fullcalendar

```
<FullCalendar
        timeZone="local"
        weekNumberCalculation="ISO"
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        dateClick={handleDateClick} 
        eventContent={renderEventContent} 
        headerToolbar={{
          start: "title myCustomDatePickerButton",
          center: "",
          end: "myCustomStepButton myCustomSettingsButton",
        }}
        titleFormat={function (date) {
          return date.date.year + "" + (date.date.month + 1) + "";
        }}
        customButtons={{
          myCustomDatePickerButton: {
            click: ""
          myCustomStepButton: {
            text: "",
          },
          myCustomSettingsButton: {
            click: function () {
              window.location.href = "";
              // ""
            },
          },
        }}
        dayHeaderContent={function (arg) {
          return Day_Names[arg.date.getDay()];
        }} 
        weekends={true} 
        showNonCurrentDates={false} 
        firstDay={false}
        formatDate={(day) => day.toLocaleString("en", { day: "numeric" })}
        events={events}
        droppable={true}
      />
```

making an application using React, and implementing a calendar using Fullcalendar api.

If touch and pull down on the weekly calendar, it becomes a monthly calendar.

I don't know how to implement this. is there any good way?

[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you achieve the touch and pull down bit? If so then you can change the current calendar view using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView . It's not really clear where you need help in your intended functionality, though. See also [ask].